# How can I create a UUID FK column in NestJS?

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I am running into an odd issue where I can't create a FK relationship between two entities.

```
// organization.entity.ts

@PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

...

@OneToMany(() => User, (user) => user.organization)
  users: User[];
```

```
// user.entity.ts

@PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column({
    type: 'uuid',
  })
  organizationId: string;

...

@ManyToOne(() => Organization, (organization) => organization.users)
  organization: Organization;
```

In my `ormconfig.json` file I have these settings (among connection creds)

```
...
"logging": true,
  "entities": [
    "dist/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}"
  ],
  "synchronize": true
...
```

I am using `"typeorm": "^0.2.45"` in my `package.json` file.

> Key columns "organizationId" and "id" are of incompatible types: character varying and uuid.

How can I create an FK relationship between users & organizations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So from your question I understood is you want a "organizationId" field in your users table which will be a FK.

To create OnetoMany Relation between Organization and users do as below:

```
// organization.entity.ts

@Entity({ name: 'organizations' })
export class Organization {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

...

  @OneToMany(() => User, (user) => user.organization)
  users: User[];
}
```

```
// user.entity.ts

@Entity({ name: 'users' })
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column({ type: 'uuid' })
  organizationId: string;

...

  @ManyToOne(() => Organization, (organization) => organization.users)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'organizationId' })
  organization: Organization;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I am curious, is it good practice to include the `JoinColumn`? I didn't need to do that on my `organization->locations` entity.

Comment: In case of OnetoMany relationship you can omit `JoinColumn` option, but in OnetoOne relations it is necessary to use `JoinColumn` to specify which table contains the FK.