# How can I create a primary Key (UUID) with a one to many relationship in NestJS

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I am really struggling with this and I'm not sure why.

I have two tables: `users` and `organizations`. A user can belong to an organization, and an organization can have many users.

From [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71976449/how-can-i-create-a-uuid-fk-column-in-nestjs/71978466?noredirect=1#comment127198881_71978466) I thought I had resolved my issue, but it seems I haven't.

Here is my `ormconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "type": "postgres",
  "host": "localhost",
  "port": 5432,
  "username": "username",
  "password": "password",
  "database": "mydb",
  "logging": true,
  "entities": [
    "dist/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}"
  ],
  "synchronize": true
}
```

In my `organization.entity.ts` file I have this:

```
...
@PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

@Column()
  name: string;

@OneToMany(() => User, (user) => user.organization)
  users: User[];
```

In my `user.entity.ts` file, I have this:

```
@PrimaryColumn({
    type: 'uuid',
  })
  id: string;

@Column({ type: 'uuid' })
  organizationId: string;

@ManyToOne(() => Organization, (organization) => organization.users)
  @JoinColumn({
    name: 'organizationId',
  })
  organization: Organization;
```

When I start my local development server via `npm run start:dev` I get this error:

```
query failed: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_f3d6aea8fcca58182b2e80ce979" FOREIGN KEY ("organizationId") REFERENCES "organizations"("id") ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION

detail: 'Key columns "organizationId" and "id" are of incompatible types: character varying and uuid.',
```

It seems that I'm setting both column types to be `uuid`, so I'm not sure where it's getting the different column types.

I have the same relationship without issue on my Organizations --> Locations. What am i doing wrong with the Organization --> User relationship to cause the error?

Comment: Could you try not specifying the type in you `@Column` decorator of the `organizationId` field?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I must have had something very wrong with my application. I started a fresh NestJS application and everything works fine. Thank you for your suggestion!